# Invalid postback or callback argument on gridview click

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
        runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 

        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

My code

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
public partial class del : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Country") });
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = GridView1.SelectedRow.RowIndex;
        string name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
        string country = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        string message = "Row Index: " + index + "\\nName: " + name + "\\nCountry: " + country;
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + message + "');", true);
    }
}
```

While clicking on the row is should show row.. but showing error invalid postback...
need help

Comment: Can you tell us more about your error structure ?. Are you getting callback argument error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>` below your gridview and change `EnableEventValidation="false"` on top of your page

This will definetly work for you.